# How to get function inside a class?

Tags: python, function, django-models, django-views, attributeerror

I am beginner so apology for any mistake. I was trying to follow the django tutorial of telusko in which he make a tour website .Well I am trying to make my own ecommerce website to sell computer parts as a practice. I was trying to make my html dynamic by writing a class in models. So I was trying to get the specification of any product(e.g. graphic cards) in html page in a dynamic way.

Here is my model:

```
 from django.db import models


class Product:
    id = int
    name = str
    img = str
    information = str
    price = float
    specs1 = str
    specs2 = str
    value1 = float
    testspecs = {"spec4": "value4"}

    def spec1(self, name, value):
        self.name = str
        self.value = str
        return name, value
```

Here is my Views:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Product


def index(request):
    product1 = Product()
    product1.name = 'GTX force 3D vector 7'
    product1.information = "  This is very gud graphic card. I mean it sucks your money a lot. By performance I guarantee that it can easily waste a lot of your garbage time and life like... like 20 hours a day. "
    product1.price = 780000
    product1.specs1 = "No. of Cores"
    product1.value1 = 3
    product1.spec1.name = "Clock Speed"
    product1.spec1.value = "1530 MHz "

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'product1': product1})


def cart(request):
    return render(request, 'cart.html')
```

As you can see in my views I want to have some way in which I can easily specify the specs of my graphic card(e.g. clock speed) and there  value(in that case 1530 MHz) in same one property/function so that I can easily put specs and value of that specs in admin page(if you follow telusko tutorial, later he will transfer them to admin. I was following him.). I know this code is wrong. I get Attribution error: AttributeError at /home/
'method' object has no attribute 'name'" . The proble was in the `{{product1.spec1.name}}`For that reason I am here to seek help.

Here is my HTML page I am trying to make dynamic:

```
    <!-- for cards -->

<!-- for card-1 -->
<div class="card text-center  border-secondary mb-3 shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-body rounded" style="width: 18rem;">
    <img src="shopingdata\Current items\i1.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="..">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{ product1.name}}</h5>


        <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus quam maiores voluptatibus
            autem, itaque saepe, non sed ratione incidunt neque culpa quidem veniam. Adipisci libero voluptas officiis
            quibusdam illo. Sapiente.</p>
        <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
            <div class="accordion-item">
                <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
                    <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                        data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        Information
                    </button>
                </h2>
                <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne"
                    data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                    <div class="accordion-body">
                      {{product1.information}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-header">
                Specifications
            </div>

            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li class="list-group-item">
                    <strong>{{product1.specs1}}</strong>
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item">{{product1.value1}}</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">
                    <strong>Cores</strong>
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item">16</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">
                    <strong>{{product1.spec1.name}}</strong>
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item">900 rpm</li>

            </ul>
            <hr>
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <strong>Price</strong>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item"> {{product1.price}} PKR</li>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add to cart</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Please make it easy. I am an alone baby in this world. Thanks

Comment: There's a lot wrong with your class definition. I would start by looking at [the official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html). Why are you assigning a bunch of class variables like this: `id = int`? I think you meant to use type annotations, but instead, you are creating class variables.

Comment: *Why* are you doing `self.name = str`??

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga is it wrong? I did not get any error because of that. I was trying to make a variable with no value but with type defined like in javascript..

Comment: Now I understood what were you saying. I should use ` id: int` . Btw why I don't any errors because of that.

Comment: Because what you did wouldn't produce any errors, it just doesn't do what you think it was doing

Answer (score 0):

Id recommend you define your classes like this:

```
class product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    specs = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    id = models.CharField(primary_key = True,max_length=10)
    
    def __str__(self):
       return "product: "+ self.name
```

Create your objects manually in the Django Admin panel or maybe use a form, then when you'd like to reference a product on your site, user something like...

```
selected_product = product.objects.get(pk = "Id you're looking for")
```

Then to access the name or specs you can try something like

```
print(f"Product name: {selected_product.name} , product value: {selected_product.value}")
```

Is this what you're trying to accomplish?